# Createing a Sphinx code-block, with inline text parsing

Tags: html, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, text-parsing

I'm trying to create a directive, that will allow me to parse links inside a Sphinx `CodeBlock` directive. I looked at the `ParsedLiteral` directive from docutils, which does something like that, only it doesn't do syntax highlighting, like `CodeBlock`. I tried replacing the part of `CodeBlock` (in sphinx/directives/code.py), which generates the `literal_block`:

```
literal: Element = nodes.literal_block(code, code)
```

with

```
text_nodes, messages = self.state.inline_text(code, self.lineno)

literal: Element = nodes.literal_block(code, "", *text_nodes)
```

which is what docutils `ParsedLiteral`directive does, but I of course kept the rest of the Sphinx `CodeBlock`. This parses the code correctly, but does not apply the correct syntax highlighting, so I'm wondering where the syntax highlighting is taking place, and why it's not taking place in my modified `CodeBlock` directive.

I'm very confused as to why this is the case and I'm looking for some input from smarter people than me.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax highlights are applied at the translation phase, see `sphinx.writers.html.HTMLTranslator.visit_literal_block`:

```py
def visit_literal_block(self, node: Element) -> None:
    if node.rawsource != node.astext(): # <<< LOOK AT HERE
        # most probably a parsed-literal block -- don't highlight
        return super().visit_literal_block(node)

    lang = node.get('language', 'default')
    linenos = node.get('linenos', False)
    # do highlight...
```

Once the node's `rawsource` is not equal to its text, the highlight will not be applied.

In your example, `code` is not equal to `text_nodes.as_text()` obviously.
Just set `literal.rawsource` to `literal.as_text()` can fix the syntax highlight.

Comment: I tried following your suggestion. First, I tried overwriting the astext() method on the node, but that throws an error saying it cannot be pickled using local methods. It seems, I would have to write a new node class completely. As a final attempt, I also tried to locally modify `visit_literal_block` and just pass on the `if node.rawsource != node.astext()`, but that didn't do any difference in terms of syntax highlighting.